# How to debug "Aw, Snap!" Chrome (when opening multiple tabs)

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

If I ctrl-click a link in my app and open ~10 tabs, for 2-3 of them I get the [image: Aw Snap]

I have no idea where to start investigating this

I am working on ASP.NET (.NET6) MVC + Knockout, dunno if this is relevant.
Looks like a memory leak of some sort, that Chrome can't handle.

Chrome Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT

Edge (also based on chromium) Error code: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure Chrome has all the permissions, also make sure you singed in before you started using it. If this doesn't work. Unistall it and install it again. If you have the same problem. Debug it with Python/Pycharm. Hope it helps.

Comment: Debugging Chrome with Python? :D